# What rel attribute should I use for css.map files?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

In my web application I have some files with extension ".css.map".

Looking on the internet I see that, as content type, I should put "application/json" so my include directive looks like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="application/json" href="resources/css/angular-chart.css.map"/>
```

Nevertheless, this does not prevent my browser to display the warning:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html
```

This warning seems to be the cause of a blank page displayed on internet explorer browser (chrome and firefox seem to be fine). After reloading the page IE does display it right, but I'd like to solve this problem at its root, by getting rid of that warning.

I think the problem is in the

```
rel="stylesheet"
```

so, what should I put there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't link to map files at all. Tools that use them will use a `X-SourceMap` header or infer the URL by adding `.map` to the URL of the actual stylesheet or JavaScript program.

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly specifying the type as json in your link tag, like so:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="application/json" href="blah">
```